# Is there a meaningful way to SCAN Redis using cursors, in parallel?

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-scan

I have this simple recursive routine to scan redis keys:

```
async function scanRedisKeys(req, res, next) {

    const client = redis.createClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });

    const run = (cursor) => {
       client.scan(cursor, 'MATCH', '*', 'COUNT', 100, (err, results) => {
           if(err){
               log.error(err);
               return res.status(400).end();
           }
           const cursor = results[0];
           for(const k of results[1]){
               res.write(k);
               res.write('\n');
           }
           if(cursor !== '0'){
               run(cursor);
           }
           else{
               res.status(200).end();
           }

        });
    }

    run('0');
}
```

it is just daisy-chaining requests in series. I can't seem to envision a way to do this in parallel (using something like async.queue with a concurrency limit), since the cursors might "overlap".

Seems like to me you just take the cursor result from the previous request - there is no meaningful or even non-error-prone way to do these in parallel? Trying to stream to client and want something smoother than big chunks in longer intervals.

Comment: the only solution I can think of is to scan different keys using a different MATCH token, but this still would be 5 separate calls in series if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to achieve better performance, note that Redis is mostly a [single-threaded](https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/benchmarks) server from the point of view of command execution. Even if you parallel `scan` requests among multiple clients, it will not necessarily result in better performance as the Redis server can only process a single `scan` command at a time.

You might be able, as you've mentioned, to have multiple clients each using a different match pattern, and achieve some level of concurrency as each client will scan a different key subset out of all keys (note that even in this can, the Redis server will process a single command simultaneously, but the over all workload is distributed among multiple clients).

```js
async function scanRedisKeys(req, res, next) {
    const pattern = '123*'; // each client should have a different pattern
    const client = redis.createClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });

    const run = (cursor, pattern) => {
       client.scan(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern, 'COUNT', 100, (err, results) => {
           if(err){
               log.error(err);
               return res.status(400).end();
           }
           const cursor = results[0];
           for(const k of results[1]){
               res.write(k);
               res.write('\n');
           }
           if(cursor !== '0'){
               run(cursor, pattern);
           }
           else{
               res.status(200).end();
           }

        });
    }

    run('0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use an external script and run it inside redis-cli

for example
`list.lua`

```
local keys = redis.call('KEYS', '*')
local result = {}

for i, key in ipairs(keys) do
    local value = redis.call('GET', key)
    result[i] = {key, value}
end

return result
```

then spawn new process using node

```
function runLsCommand() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`redis-cli EVAL "$(cat list.lua)"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }

      if (stderr) {
        reject(new Error(stderr));
        return;
      }

      resolve(stdout);
    });
  });
}
```

and run the following command

`redis-cli EVAL "$(cat list.lua)"`

Comment: I dont think this addresses the cursor challenge, this simply parallelizes it